# How to set a reference row and let other rows to divide its values?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Here is a big data frame with different cells and their mRNA expression data:

|  | A | Gene 1 | Gene 2 | Gene 3 | Gene 4 | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | 9 | 12 | 24 | 42 | 30 |  |
| Cell 2 | 3 | 6 | 12 | 21 | 15 |  |
| Cell 3 | 6 | 42 | 48 | 84 | 45 |  |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Now I want the second column to be the standard and get this:

|  | A | Gene 1 | Gene 2 | Gene 3 | Gene 4 | … |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |  |
| Cell 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| Cell 3 | 2 | 7 | 4 | 4 | 3 |  |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible way to solve your problem (assuming that your data is named `df`):

```
df[] = Map("/", df, df[2,])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try `rep` like below

```
df/df[rep(2,nrow(df)),]
```